# Programmatically bind List<String> to GridView

Tags: asp.net

Just trying a simple bind. No values are populated into the GridView however.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Bread");
        list.Add("Cheeze");
        list.Add("Wine");
        list.Add("Beer");
        list.Add("Waffles");

        GridView1.DataSource = list;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another approach

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Bread");
        list.Add("Cheeze");
        list.Add("Wine");
        list.Add("Beer");
        list.Add("Waffles");

        GridView1.DataSource = list;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        GridView1.Columns.Add(new BoundField());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you set [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to true?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

Comment: haha I noticed it was preset to false. Then it occurred to me that I need to generate my own columns.